# Relocation in a docker volume: svirt_sandbox_file_t and texrel_shlib_t

Tags: fedora, selinux, docker

I run a Docker container with a volume  that contains a executable and shared library which requires relocation.

I get: `error while loading shared libraries: /opt/J9/bin/libj9thr24.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied`

As advised here: http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/
I did a `chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /opt/J9` so that at least I can launch the program. I run `docker run --rm -v /opt/J9:/opt/J9:Z ...` (I also tried with a "z")

But to allow libraries to be relocated in memory, I found that it requires: `chcon -t texrel_shlib_t /opt/J9/bin/*`

But there can be only one label on a file, how could I combine the two??

I am running `Docker version 1.8.1.fc22, build 32b8b25/1.8.1`